# Mobile Connect - How to import list of optin numbers

Tags: mobileconnect

In our Mobile Connect account we have 3200 opt in subscribers. We want to send an sms to a portion of the all contacts lists. Our internal group provided a subset of 600 contacts phone numbers (a portion of the 3200 subscribers in Mobile Connect) only to sent an activation message to. Unable to figure out how to  upload without a "Contact Key". How do will pull that out of Mobile connect so we can associate a sms send. We do not want to send to ALL contacts. Thoughts?